# Name of algorithm that infers group sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I have an array of arrays like so:

```
var groups = [
  ['one', 'three', 'four'],
  ['two', 'three', 'six', 'seven'],
  ['three', 'four', 'five'],
]
```

From this I need to deduce the appropriate sequence of values, based on the order they are given (I gave numbers for easy example). In other words, as each array has missing data, the other arrays need to be referenced to obtain the optimal sequence of all groups. Ideal output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
```

I can write this, but I'm totally sure this is a pretty common algorithm. I just don't know the name of it. Any ideas (or an easy way to solve it)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. A typical language/runtime env/compiler etc. cannot deduce values for `one`, `two` etc. without additional logic. You mean to have a separate object where those are defined? `{one: 1, two: 2 ...}`

Comment: It's the literal sequence of the object. Like, in the first object, `one` is first in sequence, and `three` is second in sequence. But looking at the second object, you can see that `two` comes before `three`, and so can deduce that `two` would go before `three` in the first object, when merging all of them together.

Comment: And what if it cannot deduce? e.g: `['one', 'three']` `['two', 'four']`. Do you also need to handle this case?

Comment: Sounds like *union* with keeping the order of the elements.

Comment: The algorithm would need to handle it as best as it can. In the case you give, it would have no choice but to return it incorrectly. We're looking for the *optimal* deduction.

Comment: Is there any requirement that `'one'` come before `'two'` in your example?

Comment: Something about topology comes to mind, like topological sort.  Not quite right, but maybe that helps point in a useful direction...

Comment: Yeah, if there's no requirement about the order of `'one'` and `'two'`, this is just a topological sort of the directed acyclic graph formed by the union of the input paths.

Comment: It looks like a DFS on a tree where "three" is the root node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to use [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to find the shortest path in a directed acyclic graph:

1. Define a node for each unique "word"
2. Define a directed edge between neighboring "words" in a group going from left (source) to right (sink)
3. Compute the weight of each edge as some function measuring the number of times two words are next two each other in a group (need to experiment here)
4. Compute the set of [topological orderings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#CITEREFKahn1962) of the constructed DAG.
5. Compute the [shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#cite_note-clrs-2) in the DAG.

The resulting path is your solution. Note, you'll have to ensure your groups define an acyclic graph.

Comment: What is the shortest path adding to the topological sort?

Comment: The topological sort is not unique. You need a way to select one as "optimal" if possible. One way is to weigh the edges (and possibly the nodes) by some metric and find the path that optimizes a cost function. The OP needs to experiment with what that optimization would be.

Comment: This is the data I ended up using to solve the problem. *Thanks to all the other answers - they are all great as well and I upvoted htem.

Comment: Still, I don't get how the shortest path in the DAG brings anything, can you explain how the OP is supposed to use it?

Comment: The topological sorting only provides a set of equivalent possible paths. To pick the "optimal" one the weights can be used. I suggested using the shortest path. You may be thinking of shortest path as only being the path that goes from node A to node B in the fewest edges. In fact, the shortest path is defined as the "path such that the sum of the weights of its constituent edges is minimized". Therefore, the weights can be used to disambiguate between the different topological sorted paths by picking a suitable cost function.

Answer (score 1):

Let me write in php. I try to comment all lines

```
$groups = [
  ['one', 'three', 'four'],
  ['two', 'three', 'six', 'seven'],
  ['three', 'four', 'five'],
];

$maxl = 0;                                      // max length of nested arrays
foreach($groups as $item)                       // walk through array
   if ((count($item) > $maxl))                  // if current array is longer
      $maxl = count($item);                     // save it's length

$result = [];                                   // will be result

for ($i = 0; $i < $maxl; $i++)                  // vertical slice of the array
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($groups); $j++)       // loop through nested arrays
      if(isset($groups[$j][$i]) &&              // if such element is present
         !in_array($groups[$j][$i], $result))   // and not in result yet
            $result[] = $groups[$j][$i];        // add it
print_r($result);
```

But i can't understand order of five and six, so result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
    [4] => six
    [5] => five
    [6] => seven
)
```

Answer (score 1):

How it works

> ```
> path = [
>     [ "one", "three" ],
>     [ "three", "four" ],
>     [ "two", "three" ],
>     [ "three", "six" ],
>     [ "six", "seven" ],
>     [ "three", "four" ],
>     [ "four", "five" ]
> ]
>
> Operation                            Result
> ------------------------------------ ----------------------------------
> 0 push(one)                          one
> 1 splice(1, 0, three)                one,three
>
> 0 push(three)                        one,three,three
> 0 splice(2, 1) delete last double    one,three
> 1 splice(2, 0, four)                 one,three,four
>
> 0 splice(1, 0, two)                  one,two,three,four
> 1 splice(2, 0, three)                one,two,three,three,four
> 1 splice(3, 1) delete last double    one,two,three,four
>
> 0 push(three)                        one,two,three,four,three
> 0 splice(4, 1) delete last double    one,two,three,four
> 1 splice(3, 0, six)                  one,two,three,six,four
>
> 0 push(six)                          one,two,three,six,four,six
> 0 splice(5, 1) delete last double    one,two,three,six,four
> 1 splice(4, 0, seven)                one,two,three,six,seven,four
>
> 0 splice(5, 0, three)                one,two,three,six,seven,three,four
> 0 splice(5, 1) delete last double    one,two,three,six,seven,four
> 1 splice(3, 0, four)                 one,two,three,four,six,seven,four
> 1 splice(6, 1) delete last double    one,two,three,four,six,seven
>
> 0 push(four)                         one,two,three,four,six,seven,four
> 0 splice(6, 1) delete last double    one,two,three,four,six,seven
> 1 splice(4, 0, five)                 one,two,three,four,five,six,seven
> ```

Basically it gets the path of all combined items in an array with start/target pairs. Then the path is walked down and for every start and target, a look up is made to find a predecessor, or a successor. If a predecessor is found, than the item is inserted at the index and if successor after the index. If not found, the item is pushed to the end of the array.

Due the fact, that every path start and target is inserted, the result is longer (2x) than wanted. So the last duplicate items are deleted.

```js
var groups = [
      ['one', 'three', 'four'],
      ['two', 'three', 'six', 'seven'],
      ['three', 'four', 'five'],
    ];

function combination(a, r) {
    r = r || [];
    a.reduce(function (res, el) {
        el.forEach(function (item, i) {
            i && res.push([el[i - 1], item]);
        });
        return res;
    }, []).forEach(function (el) {
        function lookup(n, m, offset) {
            var index = r.indexOf(n);
            ~index ? r.splice(index + offset, 0, m) : r.push(m);
            r.indexOf(m) !== r.lastIndexOf(m) && r.splice(r.lastIndexOf(m), 1);
        }
        lookup(el[1], el[0], 0);
        lookup(el[0], el[1], 1);
    });
    return r;
}

console.log(combination(groups));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), but beware that it has multiple solutions.

In the example that you provide, your relations only give the following constraints:

- 1 and 2 are before 3
- 4 is before 5
- 6 is before 7
- 4, 5, 6 and 7 are after 3

Which means that the following solutions are correct:

- 2 1 3 4 6 7 5
- 1 2 3 6 7 4 5
- 2 1 3 6 4 7 5

Calculating the total number of topological sorts of the provided example is left as an exercice to the reader.